# Azure VNets: "Evaluation Order" of NSGs and UDRs

Tags: azure-virtual-network

We're building a Hub & Spoke network in Azure with NSGs at the spoke network's subnets.
Now we'd like to allow a workload in one of the spokes to make outbound connections to a destination on the internet (TCP, 443). The traffic shall be sent though an NVA in the hub network.

The UDR of the spoke's subnet is configured like this:

`Address Prefix: 0.0.0.0/0, Next Hop Type: Virtual Appliance, Next Hop: <IP of Firewall>`

How do we need to configure the NSG's outbound rules in this particular scenario?

**a)** `Allow, Source: Virtual Network, Destination: Virtual Network`

**b)** `Allow, Source: Virtual Network, Destination: IP Addresses, Destination IP: <IP of Firewall>`

**c)** `Allow, Source: Virtual Network, Destination: Any`

IMO a) and b) would mean, that the UDR is "evaluated" first, while option c) would mean, that the NSG is applied before the routing takes place.

I very much appreciate you're help and/or links to some documentation on this topic I wasn't able to find so far.

Answer (score 1):

•   According to what you have asked with regards to the priority of consideration by **Azure Network Resource Management fabric** and its design by default, the first priority will be given to the UDR (User Defined Rule) in which the ***source and destination IP addresses are correctly defined between the virtual networks*** even if a network virtual appliance is used for forwarding the traffic in between them because when a virtual network is created, Azure automatically routes for every subnet defined during its creation. Thus, when routes are created, the first and priority routes are created and implemented for address ranges that are defined address spaces within the same virtual network, hence implying that by design, the default **evaluation priority is given to those UDR if their priority is not set by the user whose source and destination reachable valid IP addresses are correctly defined**. Please refer to the below workflow diagram for good understanding: -

[image: UDR workflow]

•   Thus, as per your post, you have asked the evaluation priority for the below UDRs: -

```
  a)    Allow, Source: Virtual Network, Destination: Virtual Network

  b)    Allow, Source: Virtual Network, Destination: IP Addresses, Destination IP: <IP of Firewall>

  c)    Allow, Source: Virtual Network, Destination: Any
```

Of the above, the **second (b)** formatted UDR will be evaluated as ***‘first’*** in priority, then the **first UDR (a)** in priority and then the **third (c)**UDR as it is defined for any IP address originating from the virtual network without any defined destination.

•   Hence, accordingly, you should go with creating the UDRs in the second (b) format as it will get by **default prioritized and ‘evaluated’ correctly** by Azure. For more information regarding this topic, kindly refer to the documentation link below: -

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-networks-udr-overview#default

http://gowie.eu/index.php/azure/best-practice/23-nsg-best-practice

Answer (score 1):

From my test(build such one vnet/subnets environment, like [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/tutorial-create-route-table-portal)), the c) might be the right answer, **which means that the NSG applies first than UDR.**

From another point of view, we can also deduce that NSG might be the higher level mechanism than UDR(NSG is at transport/application layer, and UDR is at IP layer). Because we can choose 'Port' and 'Protocol' params for NSG, but only 'IP' for UDR.

I haven't found any official related MS document about it and above conclusion is from my practice.